# How can I open an external link from a PWA in iOS that opens as a Safari browser?

Tags: ios, hyperlink, progressive-web-apps, external

I have the following problem:
I have a PWA in iOS and I want to open an external link(`<a>...</a>`) (Not as a PWA window) as a download link. A new window opens, but unfortunately I can't get back into the PWA. I am virtually stuck in the iOS download window.
Using `target="_blank"` does not help unfortunately.

Does anyone have the same problem and know how to solve it?

Many kind regards